# PowerApps: Use LookUp function instead of Filter function in PowerApps Formula

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I already wrote logic to:

- `Filter` **ScanItems** table based on **Location** drop down control
- Search in **ScanAItems** table based on **TextBox_SearchInventory.Text**
- Add particular columns in results
- Sort the result

Now, the issue is with the **Location** column in **ScanItems** table as it is applying the outer join on the table.

I am willing to apply `Inner Join` and to do that I think I need to use `LookUp` function.

Existing working code with `Filter` function

```
 SortByColumns(
    Search(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(Scans, Location.'Location Name' = varLocationGlobal.'Location Name'), //Use LookUp for this Filter
            "LocationText",
            Location.'Location Name')
        , TextBox_SearchInventory.Text
        , "cr7d5_culebracategory" 
        , "cr7d5_culebraproductname"
        , "cr7d5_culebrasku"
        , "cr7d5_culebramanufacturer"
        , "LocationText"
    ),
    "cr7d5_culebrasku",
    SortOrder.Ascending
 )
```

I want a LookUp function at line #4.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you please add context? Filter gives you a list of items (Search and SortByColumns make sense). If you replace it with LookUp, you end up with a single record (why search or sort?)

Comment: @mmikesy90: It is as it is because it will be returning multiple records linked to that single Location filter - and that's what I want now. Items without location should not appear there.

Comment: @JustDoIt: I tried putting `LookUp` function in some possible approaches I can think of but all of them were wrong considering the formula formats & supported child/parent functions. Basically the formulas were never compiled successfully.

Comment: `LookUp` function will return *only one record* which satisfies your conditions. As you want multiple records linked to the single Location, you will have to use `Filter` function and not the `LookUp` function.